# Is it possible to ignore case sensitivity of column headings in Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In the M language is there a way to ignore case when using commands like `Table.TransformColumnTypes`?   I had a column named "Task" that was renamed "TASK" and is now causing an Expression Error.  I didn't expect column headings to be case sensitive since that's not normally an issue in SQL.

The step formula looks like this:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Task", type text}, {"Employee Name", type text}})
```

which returns this error:

> Expression.Error: The column 'Task' of the table wasn't found.
>   Details:
>       Task

As I go through and adjust the case of each instance of "Task", I also get errors with these commands that are still referencing the "Task" field:

```
Table.Group
Table.RemoveColumns
Table.Sort
Table.TransformColumns
Table.TransformColumnTypes
Text.Combine
```

Note that I found an [article](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/10/27/tame-case-sensitivity-power-query-powerbi/) about using `Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` but that appears to apply to data in the table and not the column headings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be ignored,but you can rename all the column names by this formula:

```
= Table.RenameColumns(YourTableName,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(YourTableName),each {_,Text.Proper(_)}))
```

`Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` only can be used in this condition:

```
= Text.Contains("abc","A", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) //returns true
```

Comment: In some cases, renaming column names won't work. For example, I just came across this issue yesterday and data have already been lost because the column names passed to `Table.ExpandRecordColumn` is not the same as the ones in data source.

Comment: If you need to change the column names frequently,using `Table.ColumnNames` or `Record.FieldNames` to dynamically reference the column names instead of fixed column names,it can avoid errors caused by renaming columns effectively.

Comment: My data source is JSON. Not sure if dynamic column reference is possible?